# make temporary database with sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I wanna make a temporary database but I don't know I going in the right way or not
I get the error no such table: list but I don't know why python raise that error
this is my code:

```
def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS list (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , namee VARCHAR , number INTEGER ,"
       " price INTEGER )"
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def insert(name, number, price):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO list VALUES (NULL ,?,?,?,?,?)", (name, number, price)
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM list"
    )
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def delete(id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM list WHERE id=?", (id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


connect()
```

and this is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\memory.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(insert('pizza',2,6))
  File "D:\python\WindowsProject\app\user\memory.py", line 17, in insert
    cur.execute(
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: list
```

Answer (score 3):

`sqlite3.connect(":memory:")` creates an in-memory database that only exists as long as the connection is in use.

The problem is that you're closing the database connection in each function. As soon as you close it, the in-memory database vanishes. `INSERT` fails because the table no longer exists.

You'll need to preserve (or pass) the `conn` and `cur` objects so that you can use them between functions.

Comment: Hi, after 13 days of trying to find the answer to this problem with edit the code and searching on the web I don't find the answer to my question,
can you give me the code for that???